# box2dlights diffuse lights makes everything dark

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I'm playing with box2dlights but I don't understand well the use of diffuse light, and I can't find any documentation anywhere...

I have problems depending on the RayHandler settings:

If I enable the diffuse light in the Ray Handler and the shadows or the blur is active, everything is dark and I don't see any light (not even the ambiance one).

In the other hand, if the diffuse lights are disabled

```
RayHandler.useDiffuseLight(false);
```

or the blurNum is 0, or the blur is disabled, and the shadows are disabled too, the lights are rendered...

Any ideas of why is this happening?
Is the diffuse light incompatible with shadows or blurring?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set ambient light in a different way otherwise it will not have any lighting at all. Use this instead:

```
setAmbientLight(float r,float g,float b,float alpha)
```